# No ejecuta bloque Try/Catch en Formulario

Tags: java, formularios, jframe

Hice una calculadora básica con formularios y al querer manejar la `ArithmeticException() by zero` pareciera no entrar al catch y ejecutar las sentencias que defino para tal caso (ni System.out.println, ni JOptionPane.showMessage, ni jtxt_calcu.setText).

- Botón igual (=) que ejecuta el metodo ´calc´

  ```
  private void btn_igualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

  memoria2=jtxt_calcu.getText();
  jtxt_todo.setText(jtxt_todo.getText()+" "+ memoria2);
  try {
      jtxt_calcu.setText(this.calc(memoria1, signo, memoria2));
  }
  catch (ArithmeticException e) {
      jtxt_calcu.setText("Error al dividir por cero");
      System.out.println("Error al dividir por cero");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al dividir por cero");
  }
  flag=true;   
  }
  ```
- Método .calc

  ```
  public String calc (String memoria1, String signo, String memoria2)throws ArithmeticException {
  Double resultado=0.0;
  String respuesta = "";
  if (signo.equals("+")){
      resultado = Double.parseDouble (memoria1) + Double.parseDouble (memoria2);
      respuesta = resultado.toString();
  }
  if (signo.equals("-")){
      resultado = Double.parseDouble (memoria1) - Double.parseDouble (memoria2);
      respuesta = resultado.toString();
  }
  if (signo.equals("*")){
      resultado = Double.parseDouble (memoria1) * Double.parseDouble (memoria2);
      respuesta = resultado.toString();
  }
  if (signo.equals("/")){
      resultado = Double.parseDouble(memoria1) / Double.parseDouble(memoria2);
      respuesta = resultado.toString();
  }
  if (respuesta.endsWith(".0")){
      respuesta = respuesta.replace(".0","") ;
  }
  return  respuesta;
  }
  ```

Todo esto está dentro del Source de la calculadora.

**El output del programa cuando se divide por CERO es siempre ´Infinity´en mi campo de texto jtxt_calcu**

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer que funcione este manejo de excepción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muy buena pregunta...

La cuestión es:

- Los `int`se codifican en binario complemento a 2, que permite representar todos los enteros entre (-2^31) y (2^31 - 1)
- Los `long` se codifican en binario complemento a 2, que permite representar todos los enteros entre (-2^63) y (2^63 - 1)
- Por el contrario, los números en punto flotante (`float` y `double`) se codifican con el [estándar IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). La diferencia que nos importa es que *este estándar define valores especiales como `0`, `Infinity` y `NaN` ("Not A Number", no es un número)*. Y el estándar define que cuando divides un número de punto flotante por 0 obtienes infinito; [aquí explica un poco el razonamiento de esta definición](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682005/why-does-division-by-zero-in-ieee754-standard-results-in-infinite-value)

Así que:

- Cuando divides por cero en una operación de enteros (`int` o `long`) obtienes un valor que no puedes representar en la variable. La única opción para no dejar la variable con un valor "inválido" es lanzar la excepción.
- Cuando divides por cero en una operación de punto flotante (`float` o `double`) el estándar te da un valor que asignar a la variable, y te dice que ése es el resultado correcto. No hay que lanzar excepción.

Si quieres controlar esa posibilidad, lo más sencillo sería comprobar si [`Double.isInfinite(valor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isInfinite(double)) te devuelve `true` o `false`; no sólo te comprobará el caso de que dividas por cero sino también cualquier otro overflow.

Comment: Ah! Entonces por eso no estaría arrojando un error; porque trabajo con `Doubles`. Si trabajara con variables `int` sí habría error y lo manejaría el bloque Catch verdad?

Comment: Eso mismo. No es que haya un fallo, es que funciona así. Una cosa a tener en cuenta es que si mezclas `double`s e `int`s en una operación (p.ej. `5.0D/0`), antes de hacer la operación los `int` se convertirán en `double` automáticamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Tu respuesta me ha resuelto la vida una vez más!

Comment: De nada. Una cosa que se me olvidaba; una alternativa a `Double` y `Float` en algunos casos podría ser `java.math.BigDecimal`. Es útil cuando quieres trabajar con números decimales sin los redondeos de los tipos de punto flotante. Es útil para números que se puedan representar sin necesitar exponente.