# Problema error NaN o infinity error

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

Hola tengo un problema con un textfield cuando trato de mostrar el resultado de un calculo. probé con convertirlo a String y todo pero me dice  error NaN o infinity error. Mejor les muestro unas imágenes para q me ayuden.
la primera imagen muestra el código del jframe. la segunda imagen muestra el código del método que realiza el calculo. El problema es que cuando ingreso los datos y le doy a calcular me aparece Infinity en ves del resultado en el textfield. 
No puedo encontrar el problema desde hace ya como 3 días, les agradecería una solución. soy nuevo acá, saludos. Disculpe que haya puesto imagenes y no el codigo no me di cuenta, no se muy bien cual es el problema por eso no pongo la pregunta especifica, sepan disculpar. desde ya gracias.

ESTE ES EL SOURCE DEL JFRAME DE NETBEANS DONDE ESTA EL CODIGO DE LOS JFIELDTEXT Y EL BOTTON CALCULAR. 
package calculoHumedad;

```
public class calculohumedad extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    double sueloSeco, sueloHumedo, porcentajeHumedad;
    int humedad1;
    String humedad;

    public calculohumedad() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jtsuelohumedo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jtsueloseco = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jthumedad = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        calcular = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("     Suelo Humedo");

        jLabel2.setText("        Suelo Seco");

        jLabel3.setText("         Humedad");

        jtsuelohumedo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jtsuelohumedoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jtsueloseco.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jtsuelosecoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        calcular.setText("calcular");
        calcular.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                calcularActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jtsuelohumedo)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 101, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(calcular, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jtsueloseco))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jthumedad))))
                .addGap(0, 16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jtsuelohumedo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jtsueloseco)
                    .addComponent(jthumedad))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(calcular, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jtsuelohumedoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        sueloHumedo = Double.parseDouble(this.jtsuelohumedo.getText());
    }                                             

    private void jtsuelosecoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        sueloSeco = Double.parseDouble(this.jtsueloseco.getText());
    }                                           

    private void calcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        calculo micalculo = new calculo();
        humedad = String.valueOf(micalculo.calcular(sueloHumedo, sueloSeco));

        jthumedad.setText(humedad);
        System.out.print(humedad);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(calculohumedad.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(calculohumedad.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(calculohumedad.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(calculohumedad.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new calculohumedad().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton calcular;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jthumedad;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jtsuelohumedo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jtsueloseco;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Y ESTE ES EL CODIGO O METODO DEL CALCULO Q ESTA EN OTRA CLASE PERO MISMO PAQUETE,

package calculoHumedad;

```
public class calculo {

    double sueloHumedo, sueloSeco, porcentajeHumedad;

    public double calcular(double sueloHumedo, double sueloSeco){
    porcentajeHumedad = ((sueloHumedo-sueloSeco) * 100) / sueloSeco;
    return porcentajeHumedad;
}
}
```

[image: Ésta es la imagen de lo que pasa]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor revisa [help] y [ask]. Tu pregunta está bien, pero deberías mostrar el código como texto, no como capturas de pantalla. Adicionalmente, estaría bien que revisaras (debug o `System.out.println`) como funciona tu programa; por ejemplo ver que valores tienen `sueloHumedo` y `sueloSeco` antes de la operación, o si se llama a los métodos donde se asignan los valores a esas variables, para hacer las preguntas más concisas.

Comment: Pon el código en formato texto, en vez de capturas de pantalla, para que pueda ser reproducible y poder ayudarte

Comment: Gracias por el cambio. He recuperado la captura de pantalla, que sí era útil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me enrollo un poco, pero es para que veas el proceso para depurar tú en un futuro.

Un valor de `Infinity` indica, entre otros casos, [una división de un número por 0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96958/no-ejecuta-bloque-try-catch-en-formulario/96966#96966).

Naturalmente, eso significa que o no asignas valores a los atributos y se quedan con el valor por defecto (0), o les asignas un valor 0.

El código de `jtsuelohumedoActionPerformed` y de `jtsuelosecoActionPerformed` es suficientemente sencillo como para descartar la seguna posibilidad, así que la cuestión es si esos métodos son llamados.

Así que parece que el `actionPerformed` no está siendo invocado<sup>1</sup>, así que busco cuándo se invoca este método en los `JTextField` y [encuentro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126114/how-to-apply-actionperformed-to-jtextfields-in-java), que básicamente explica que el `actionPerformed` del listener se ejecuta *cuando pulsas `Intro` dentro del `JTextField`*.

Así que, sencillamente, no se está lanzando el evento y los atributos no se inicializan. Puedes tratar de jugar con otros listeners como `DocumentListener` o `FocusListener`, pero lo más sencillo es meter toda la lógica en `calcularActionPerformed`, ya que de todas formas no usas ninguno de los datos antes de invocar a ese método.

---

<sup>1</sup>Añadiendo un par de líneas de log a esos métodos lo podrías haber detectado y haber investigado eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias SJuan76 ese era el problema y lo explicaste perfecto. Ahora vamos a seguir avanzando y aprendiendo. Saludos

Comment: @Andres puedes aceptar esta respuesta como correcta si resuelve tu problema, por favor.